# Viewer Node and Node Wrangler not working

Tags: add-on, shader-nodes

I'm trying to add a [`Viewer Node`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/viewer.html) in the *Shader Editor* but doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> doesn't work. I activated [`Node Wrangler`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/node/node_wrangler.html) and the keyboard shortcut for Viewer Node isn't even listed. I tried restarting Blender after node activation and it still doesn't work. Is there a way to add a Viewer Node via dropdown menus? I'm using the latest 3.3.0 version.

Comment: Shader editor does not have VIEWER NODE, just the compositor

Comment: I think the latest version (3.3) omits the _Viewer_ node (which was just a weak emission shader), and now it just connects the selected node directly to the Material Output (basically the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post OP but I've found that on top of what the other commenter Christopher said (ctrl shift doesn't give a separate node anymore) that you have to double click for it to do anything (on default settings).

Comment: Where do you have to double-click? Apart from the disposed separate Viewer node (in the _Shader Editor_, in the _Geometry Nodes Editor_ you still have it) it still works with Ctrl+Shift and a single left-click like before in my Blender versions, including 3.6.5, 4.0.0 and 4.1 Alpha.

Comment: when this comment was made I was using 3.5 and in shader editor if you want to get the viewer/preview mode shown in a lot of older tutorials it does still seem to be that you need to double click - but it's also not necessary anymore as others above said (but can confuse a beginner)

Comment: I just mentioned 3.6.5, 4.0 and 4.1 because those I had available at that moment to verify it, but I cannot remember having to double-click at any time since I started using the node wrangler... but I'm not at a PC right now to download an older version to check that.

Comment: Just tested 3.2.2, no double-click necessary.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann interesting, I've checked on my version (currently on 3.6 I think), old version I have (3.5 and 3.1), and 4.0 and whatever's the latest via Steam and still, like OP can't get the viewer node. Have yet to find another solution even on blank slate downloads, but I wonder if it could be a bug or issue with certain GPUs or Windows settings (harder to test, I only have 1 device).